# Is it a good practice to use svn for two different applications but on the same server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, subversion

Is it a good practice to use SVN for two different applications but on the same server ?
I'm asking this because, whenever I update one of the application with svn it does not ask for password everytime, however when I try to update second application with SVN it asks for password only for first time and then it don't.
But as per my observations first application again asks for password right after when I update second application and vice versa.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Do you mean that you have two repositories on the same server? Why would there be anything wrong with that?

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem with using two or more SVN repos on the same server. If a development server couldn't host more than one SVN at a time, that would be a serious waste of storage and money.

When you use SVN, your password is not cached on the server-side but on your computer. SVN is stateless. That means that in fact, your local copy must authenticate each time it does an access to your repo. But your client can store the password for a limited time so that you don't need to enter it manually each time. In your case, it appears that storing a password for one repo make your SVN client forget about any previous password. Nothing wrong about that, but it can be a little disturbing.

You can configure the way SVN stores your passwords in `~/.subversion/config` to gain more control.